# Accessing Sub-document ID in mongoDB using node express framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to access a sub-document ID in mongoDB using node.js, but getting null output from the statement : 
review = location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);

Also, results are getting printed in the console, but in the browser, I am getting an error saying that "reviewId not found"

[image: Data is getting printed in the console]

[image: This is the main code]

[image: Data is present in the database]

[image: This is the output that I am getting]

Comment: Instead od `location.reviews.id(req.params.reviewid);` use `location.reviews.find(function(review){return review.id === req.params.reviewid;});`

Comment: @Molda Its still giving the same output

Comment: What is the output of console.log(review); after `review = location.reviews.find(function(review){return review.id === req.params.reviewid;});`

Comment: it says "undefined".

Comment: review = location.reviews.find(function(review){
    return review.id === req.params.reviewid;
   });
This is what i have added. Before this change, the statement gave "null". Now its undefined

Comment: Add console.log(review) before *return* in find function. Output?

Comment: This gives me the correct data on console. Getting the proper review

Comment: Then the issue is comparing ids. Try this in find function `console.log(typeof review.id, typeof req.params.reviewid);`

Comment: Well first one is "Object". Second one is "String"

Comment: Cool then you need to change req.params.id to ObjectID. I'm not sure how it's done in mongoose try search for *mongoose string to ObjectID*

Comment: Maybe mongoose.ObjectId(req.params.id) but not sure

Comment: Thanks I'll check :)

Comment: I checked various places but couldnt find any correct solution.
Do you have some idea?
Kindly let me know

Comment: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.reviewid)` should work

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provide `$elemMatch`  to search inside sub-document. You may try

```
 db.locations.find( { _id: ObjectId("Your_locations_Id"), reviews: { $elemMatch: { id: ObjectId("Your_reviews_Id") } }})
```

in mongo shell. I am not sure about mongoose but should work following

```
Loc.find("_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.locationid)).elemMatch("reviews", {"id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.reviewsid)})
```

Please have a look [MongoDB $elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) and [mongoose elemMatch](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch) function